# Multi Select Dropdown Not selected

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I want to load multi-select dropdwon form and if $val found in $opt then show them as selected but it seems the problem lies on (in_array function doesn't search the arrays each other) doesn't compare.

I have the following code...

```
<div class="controls">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputWei"><?=_('Display')?></label>
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="disp[] ">
    <select id="" class="input-xlarge multiselect" parent="" title="" rel="tooltip_right" name="disp[]" multiple="multiple" style="display: none;" data-original-title="">
    <?php 
        $genD = "Men, Women, Both";
        $opt = explode(',',$genD); 
        $gen = "Men, Women";
        $val = explode(',', $gen);       
        foreach($opt as $option){
            $selected = in_array(trim($val),$opt)?'selected="selected"':'';
            ?>
        <option <?=$selected?> value="<?=trim($option)?>"><?=trim($option)?></option>

 <?php  } ?>

    </select>
</div>
```

some one help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is not on `in_array()`, but in your use of `trim()`. `trim` does not works on arrays, only on strings. you have to trim each value separatly.
Also, you have the `in_array` parameters inverted

something like this should work. you could also use [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) to modify the array in place

```
$val = explode(',', $gen);   
$copy = array();
foreach ($val as $v){
    $copy[] = trim($v);
}
$val = $copy;
foreach($options as $option){
    $selected = in_array($option, $val)?'selected="selected"':'';
    ?>
```

Comment: I can see my problem now, Thanks For your help. you got it.